# Largest possible value of consecutive integers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Find the **largest** possible value of $k$ for which $3^{11}$ is expressible as the **sum of $k$ consecutive positive integers?**

Comment: $k_{max}=3^5$...

Comment: How i can get it? plz elaborate.

Comment: I'll expand this comment in the answer now.

Comment: It was my wrong suggestion... Correct answer is $2\cdot 3^5$.

Comment: @Oleg567 : Could you write $k_\max$ instead of $k_{max}$?  You can code it as k_\max (no {curly braces} are needed). ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edition 2**.

(Thanks to **Antonio Vargas** and **String**!)

$$3^{11} = a+(a+1)+(a+2)+\cdots+(a+k-1) = k \dfrac{2a+k-1}{2}.$$

$$2\cdot 3^{11} =  k (2a+k-1).$$

So, $k$ must be divisor of $2\cdot 3^{11}$, thus $k$ must have form $k = 3^b$ or $k = 2\cdot 3^b$.

The largest possible $k$ here is $$k_{\max}=2\cdot3^5=486.$$

Then $2a+k-1=3^6$, $a=122$.

---

Comment: How can we show that $k$ is odd?

Comment: $3^b$ is odd anyway ($b\in \mathbb{N}$). Right?

Comment: Exactly.. i didn't get the last line. K is a factor of 3^b but from there how we r getting the largest value of k is 3^5?

Comment: If $k=3^6$, then $\left(a+\dfrac{3^6-1}{2}\right)>3^5$, so their product is greather then $3^{11}$. And other $3^b$ for $b>6$ too.

Comment: ok ok got it. Thanks

Comment: It seems that by asserting that $k|3^{11}$ you've assumed that $k$ is odd, i.e. that $2|(2a+k-1)$.  It isn't obvious to me why the first equation has no solutions when $k$ is even.

Comment: @AntonioVargas: You are quite right. The correct answer is $k=2\cdot 3^5$ which can be seen in this [Wolfram Alpha Computation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+n%2C+n%3D364-3%5E5%2B1+to+364%2B3%5E5)

Comment: odd^something is always odd. it follows the property of index irrespective of the property of power. here 3 is odd so 3^b must be odd

Comment: @R.Chakraborty The point is that the statement $k|3^{11}$ wasn't correct. It should really have been $k|(2)3^{11}$.

Comment: Yes, @String, you are right. I'll delete my answer, ang you'll write your correct answer. Very nice and helpful note. +1!

Comment: @Oleg567: Great! It was a minor, but still important point, initially made by Antonio Vargas ;)

Comment: @Oleg567: I suggest you correct your answer instead ...

Comment: Or maybe I should add my rendering of it just to add one perspective ... :)

Comment: @String, ha-ha, thank you :)

Comment: Thanks to all. it helped a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE**: I personally prefer the [concise answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/847515/94971) given by [Oleg567](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/47993/oleg567). Nevertheless, for the variety in approaches, here is my rendering of it ...

Suppose
$$
3^{11}=\sum_{i=a}^{b}i=k\cdot\mu
$$
where $k$ is the number of summands in the sum above and $\mu=\frac{a+b}{2}$ is the average summand. Now we divide into two cases

1. If $k$ is odd, $\mu$ is an integer and has to be odd, since $k\cdot\mu=3^{11}$ is odd. Since $a=\mu-\lfloor 0.5k\rfloor$ we see that $k$ has to be less than twice the value of $\mu$ for $a$ to be positive. The largest $k$ dividing $3^{11}$ with this property is $k=3^5$.
2. If $k$ is even, $\mu=x+0.5$ for some integer $x$. Thus $k\cdot\mu=0.5k\cdot(2x+1)=3^{11}$. So $0.5k$ must be odd. Since in this case $a=\mu-0.5(k-1)$ we see that $k-1$ must be less than twice the value of $\mu$ and therefore it follows that $k=2\cdot 3^5$ is the largest such integer.

The winning case is when $k=2\cdot 3^5=486$ and $\mu=0.5\cdot 3^6$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
a&=0.5\cdot 3^6-0.5(2\cdot 3^5-1)&=122\\
b&=a+2\cdot 3^5-1&=607
\end{align}
$$
so that
$$
3^{11}=\underbrace{122+123+...+606+607}_{486\text{ summands}}
$$
which is supported by this [Wolfram Alpha Computation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=122%2B123%2B...%2B606%2B607).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the k integers have average a. Then $ak = 3^{11}$.

Two cases:

1) k is odd. So a is also an integer.

So k must be of the form $3^i$ with $1 \le i \le 11$.

For $k = 3^i$, $a = 3^{11-i}$. a is clearly odd. In this case, smallest of the k integers = a - (k-1)/2.

All the integers need to be positive, so $a - (k-1)/2 > 0$.

$3^{11}/k > (k-1)/2$.

$k^2 - k - 2.3^{11} < 0$.

So k lies between the two roots of this quadratic expression, $\frac{1 \pm \sqrt{(1+8.3^{11})}}{2}$. The lower one of these is negative, so we only need to worry about the higher root,

$k < \frac{1+\sqrt{(1+8.3^{11})}}{2}$. Among the candidates of the form $3^i$, this is satisfied till $k = 3^5$

2) k is even. Let k = 2l. Then a is of the form b + 0.5, for some integer b.
$l(2b+1) = 3^{11}$. Using similar logic as last time, l is of the form $3^i$ for some i.
Smallest integer here is $b - l = (3^{11}/l - 1)/2 - l$.

So the condition for all terms to be positive is $3^{11} / 2l - l > 1/2$. Again, this is satisfied till $l = 3^5$. In this case, k = $2.3^5$, which is greater than in the first case. So we choose this.

Comment: Please see the comments on the other answer.

Comment: I had started to modify the answer before I saw these, sorry.